# How do I configure a solution in VS2013 to use a project branch?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, branching-and-merging

I have a solution that includes multiple projects. I am making changes to the database that require a different schema and connection string while I'm working on this.

The Solution Explorer window looks like:

```
Solution
- BLL project
- Website project
- DAL project
- Console project
- Second website project
```

The actual directory structure actually looks like:

```
\Source\Workspaces\TeamName\BLL
\Source\Workspaces\TeamName\Website
\Source\Workspaces\TeamName\DAL
\Source\Workspaces\TeamName\Console
\Source\Workspaces\TeamName\SecondWebsite
\Source\Workspaces\TeamName\SolutionFiles
```

I can branch the individual projects that are being changed easily enough. It's at this point that I get stuck. Most of what I have found on SO and other online resources do not explain how to switch projects within a solution to the branched version.

Do I just need to create a new solution file for the branch and replace the projects within it with their branched versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branch the entire TeamName directory including the solution and all projects.

Comment: And then there's the followup: how?

If I right-click the repository name in the Source Control Explorer and tell it to branch, it brings up the branching dialog with nowhere to branch to. If I try to add somewhere, it tells me source control must branch into an existing team project. If I try to branch it into itself, then it throws an error about that, too.

Using TFS power tools, the option to branch doesn't even exist in Windows Explorer. What am I missing?

Comment: If TeamName is the name of your team project, then you need to create an extra layer of folders.  $\TeamProject\MAIN\BLL   Then you can branch MAIN -> DEV